# Selecting item in incapsulated DropDownList on DataBind

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls, page-lifecycle

I have a complex `UserControl` with the main purpose to encapsulate `DropDownList` with a number of properties for advanced manipulation.

List is being populated on `PreRender` event depending on properties previously were set:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sourceClient.SelectCommand = this.Property1 ? "exec a" : "exec b";
}
```

The most used property is ClientID:

```
[Category("Settings")]
public int ClientID
{
   get
   {
      return Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
   }
   set
   {
      DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
   }
}
```

Getter commonly is being called by `ControlPameters` in `SqlDataSources` on pages with this control.

Setter - from markup: `<uc:UserControl1 runat="server" ClientID='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />`.

So the question is:

Why does setter from `Bind` is called earlier then `PreRender`? And `DropDownList` is empty and item selecting doesn't work! How to workaround this behavior?

Edit1: Ok, not `PreRender` but `Init`. But DropDownList1_DataBinding is still being called after property setter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataBinding always occurs before `PreRender`.  From [ASP.Net Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx):

> DataBinding 
>   This event is raised by
>   data-bound controls before the
>   PreRender event of the containing
>   control (or of the Page object) and
>   marks the beginning of binding the
>   control to the data.
>
> Use this event to manually open
>   database connections, if required.
>   (The data source controls often make
>   this unnecessary.)

One solution to your issue would be to just handle the `DataBinding` event and pre-bind your dropdownlist (or even just do it during `Load`), rather than waiting all the way until `PreRender`.  This would ensure that the `DropDownList` was available when the Bind call goes off.

Another solution would be to just pass your control a reference to the datasource itself, rather than using a Bind call.  Then it could programmatically deal with binding itself at the right times - you could load your `DropDownList`, and then get your ID for it, all during `PreRender`, by accessing the datasource.

Comment: @womp: Hi, thanks for tips! I rewrote my code so now I have Page_DataBinding event handler but still first is called Page_DataBinding after it property setter and after it DropDownList1_DataBinding where it it's being populated from a data source. How to data bind drop down list before setter?